# SQL Server - How does Always On in a shared nothing config maintain transaction durability during a failover?

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, failover

I've been reading up on Always On, and I was wondering how transactional durability is maintained during a failover when using a shared nothing configuration.

The only things I can find on google talk about log shipping, but this would mean that if a failover occurs in-between log restores, then some transactions could be lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use synchronous commit mode. This means transactions committed on the primary will also be committed on the secondary (over your network). So, if you failover during a transaction it will be rolled back when the secondary is brought online after recovery.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff877931.aspx

> *Synchronous-commit mode protects your data by requiring the data to be synchronized between two places, at the cost of somewhat increasing
>   the latency of the transaction.*